# Вопрос по SFINAE

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

При прочтении книги возник вопрос по коду:

```
template <typename T>
struct IsClass {
template <class C> static True isClass( int C::* );
template <typename C> static False isClass( ... );
enum { r = sizeof(IsClass<T>::isClass<T>(0))
== sizeof(True) };
};
```

Почему код корректно работает на любых классах, вне зависимости от того есть или нет члены типа int, хотя в шаблоне функции `static True isClass( int C::* )` аргумент указатель на член класса типа int?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

Тут всё довольно просто, при компиляции с каким-либо типом, эта строчка:

```
template <class C> static True isClass( int C::* );
```

превращается во что-то такое:

```
static True isClass( int Type::* );
```

Теперь, если `Type` это какой-то встроенный тип, эта функция отбраковывается (для того, чтобы объявить указатель на член, тип должен быть классом). Если же `Type` является классом (любым), тогда это функция компилируется нормально, ведь вне зависимости от того, есть ли вообще в классе какие-либо члены, мы можем создать указатель на член. К примеру:

```
void* std::string::* ptr;
```

Другой вопрос, что нам нечем этот член инициализировать (ничего реального нет, кроме `nullptr`), но это уже дело десятое. Главное, что мы его объявили. Теперь мы можем передать туда `nullptr` или `0`.

Декларация в C++ вообще требует очень мало: чтобы использовать какой-то класс в контексте, где знание о его внутреннем устройстве и размере необязательно, достаточно вот такой предварительной декларации:

```
class SomeClass;
```

И теперь можете создавать указатели на `SomeClass`, указатели на функции `SomeClass` или, как в вопросе, указатели на поля `SomeClass`. Это поведение гарантировано стандартом C++ и описано в разделе [[dcl.mptr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.mptr)